# ToC spacing between individual section numbering and title

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, numbering

Using the `tocloft` package and `\setlength\cftsubsubsecnumwidth{4em}` successfully changes the spacing of all subsubsection numbering and titles in the table of content.

How do I change the spacing only for subsubsections 1.10.10 and 1.10.11 to mach the spacing of previous subsubsections as the title and numbering "10" and "11" are too close.

[image]

Mwe:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{title}
\setcounter{subsection}{9}
    \subsection{title}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{7}
        \subsubsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: see [problem-with-localtableofcontents-from-package-etoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633694/problem-with-localtableofcontents-from-package-etoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the odd sectional unit you could consider adding an additional space (like a tie `~`) into the ToC entry:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{3.5em}% Or whatever default you set for this sectional unit

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{title}

\setcounter{subsection}{9}
\subsection{title}

\setcounter{subsubsection}{7}
\subsubsection{title}
\subsubsection{title}
\subsubsection[~title]{title}% Alternative title in ToC
\subsubsection[~title]{title}% Alternative title in ToC
\subsubsection[~title]{title}% Alternative title in ToC

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It puts local changes into the ToC itself.

```
% tocspacesprob.tex  SE 634180

\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{4em}  %% added to match your question's description

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{title}
\setcounter{subsection}{9}
    \subsection{title}
    \setcounter{subsubsection}{7}
        \subsubsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{1em}} %% added to locally increase space
        \subsubsection{title}
        \subsubsection{title}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{-1em}} %% added to revert to "normal" space
        \subsubsection{title}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]